# Self-written Extension method isn't available within WebMethod

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, webmethod

I've written a simple extension method for a web project, it sits in a class file called **StringExtensions.cs** which contains the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Useful extensions for string
/// </summary>
static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Is string empty
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool IsEmpty(this string value)
    {
        return value.Trim().Length == 0;
    }
}
```

I can access this extension method from all the classes I have within the App_Code directory. However I have a web page called **JSON.aspx** that contains a series of **[WebMethods]** - within these I cannot see the extension method - I must be missing something very obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StringExtensions.cs file needed to have the class declared as **public**

Previously:

```
static class StringExtensions{ ... }
```

Fixed:

```
public static class StringExtensions{ ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to see the extension method you must have an `using` directive for the namespace in which the class containing the extension method is declared.

Comment: @Jon: thanks; the using *statement* is a quite different thing.

Comment: No problem - it's a very easy mistake to make. If it's any consolation, I got it wrong throughout the first draft of the first chapter of C# in Depth. I was mortally embarrassed when Eric pointed it out, given my normal pedantry around terminology.

Comment: @Jon: Currently the file containing the extension method has no namespace. I've added one (namespace Dog{}), then adding this to the JSON.aspx file (<%@ Import Namespace="Dog" %>) but it still doesn't make any difference

Comment: @Peter: Does the method work if you call it explicitly as StringExtensions.IsEmpty(text)?

Comment: @Jon: That gave "'StringExtensions' is inaccessible due to its protection level" - so I've changed the StringExtensions.cs file code from "static class StringExtensions" to "public static class StringExtensions" and that's solved it - D'oh! :)